# didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: is called, but didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called in Xcode9

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cocos2d-x-3.0

all.
I want to ask you about push notification settings.

Environments:

**MacOS[High Sierra10.13.3]**
**Xcode9.2(9C40b)**

**Devices**
- iPhone6S[iOS10.3.3]
- iPhoneX [iOS11.2.6]

**Language:**
Cocos2d-x (Objective-c)

This problem occurs suddenly, and above methods are called before,
so basic settings must have been correctly done such as "Capabilities", "Provisioning Profiles".
And of course, network is connected to wifi.

So now, here is my code snippet.

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Also, I try this one.

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* setting = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings: setting];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

I can see push notification dialog when app is launched, push allow or deny button, `requestAuthorizationWithOptions` callback is invoked, but nothing happens.
I repeatedly uninstall and install app, but nothing changed.

**Added(14/03/2018 18:53)**

I create new test project and use the same bundle identifier and Provisioning Profiles.
Then, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is invoked correctly.

So, maybe configuration of Provisioning Profiles and AppID are ok, my project's setting is incorrect...

Comment: have you got the device token? The device on which you want to test notification what is the OS installed on that.

Comment: yes, I successfully have got the device token before, but now I can't.

Comment: os are ios10.3.3 and ios11.2.6.

Comment: you have got them while testing? in debug mode? have you checked the certificates you are using are development or production?

Comment: yes, debug build, not production or adhoc. where do i check my certificates? thx for your early response!

Comment: check in your xcode, see if you are using correct certificates.

Comment: you mentioned about [Projects > Generall > Signing(Debug)]？

Comment: This problem was fixed.

Comment: Removing one sdk fix this problem...!
@SaadChaudhry thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the project is targeting iOS version 10.0+, Apple recommends utilizing the new method for asking for notification permissions:

```
requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorizationwithoptions?language=objc